# What is difference between revered and venerated words?

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

English is a foreign language for me, so I have to use a Google Translate or similar services. They give same translation to my first language, and I feel some nuances are being lost.

Examples:

> Confession with the venerated minister.

vs

> A highly revered missionary from Africa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both **venerate** and **revere** are similar in that they mean to show great respect for another person, but they are different in that **venerate** tends to be used in the context of spirituality and **revere** in the context of worldly virtues.  A saintly person would be venerated and a political leader would be revered, for example.

Comment: Except that _reverend_ (Latin for 'to be revered') is used as an honorific for members of the clergy!

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/venerate) has a compare/contrast article bringing this out well; other dictionaries tend to exaggerate the synonymity.

Comment: @KateBunting  Having studied medieval literature, I don't think immediately of the clergy when the subject is spirituality. :-)

Comment: I believe another subtle distinction is that "venerate" at least sometimes implies something *concrete*, while "revere" always describes an attitude or state of mind. You could say that someone *venerates* a saint by *doing something specific* - like dedicating a church in their name. You *can't* say someone *reveres* a political leader **by** dedicating a building (but you *could* say they *honor* the political leader by doing so).

Comment: @QuackE.Duck  Yes, I would agree that there are veneration rituals but no reverence rituals, unless the sort of deferential behavior that often accompanies reverence is considered ritualistic. But that would be stretching  the word *ritual* a little too thin, IMO.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck Could you show me an example where **venerate** licenses a complement?

Comment: @TimR I was thinking of the kind of phrase like "X venerated Y **by doing Z**. This is the kind of phrase I had learned as being a *prepositional phrase used as an adverb to modify "venerated"* ("by" is the preposition; the gerund "doing" is the object of the preposition "by"; Z is the direct object of "doing"). But, I know on ELU you don't typically refer to constructions as *prepositional phrases used as adverbs (or adjectives)*! I had thought this was the kind of thing that the community would classify as a *complement* instead, but I see I was mistaken. I'll delete that earlier comment.

Comment: @TimR A *complement* is normally something like the word "mad" in "That made them mad!" (Object complement) But, I *know* I've heard the word used here in other contexts than that. Wikipedia gives this very broad definition: "In grammar, a complement is a word, phrase, or clause that is necessary to complete the meaning of a given expression." That's what I was trying to convey: "by doing Z" adds more information to "venerated." But "X venerated Y" is complete on its own: does that disqualify the prepositional phrase from being a "complement"? I'm interested to hear how you would classify it!

Comment: @QuackE.Duck  That's what I figured you meant but I wanted to make sure.  I agree that veneration can include some activity, often ritualistic in nature, but I don't think it's a necessary element in the real world or in the verb's grammar.